# parameterise line segment or function

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

Find the work done by the force field $F =\langle x^2 
, ye^x \rangle $ to move a particle along the curve
$x = y^2 + 1$, from $A = (1, 0)$ to $B = (2, 1)$.

Can I parameterise this curve as a line segment from point $A$ to point $B$?

$$ x=(1-t)x_0+tx_1 $$

$$ x= 1+t $$

$$ y = (1-t)y_0+t(y_1) $$

$$ y=1 $$

Or do I have to parameterise the function itself?

i.e.

$$y=t $$

$$ x= t^2 +1 $$

Answer (score 1):

The parametrization

$$ x=(1-t)x_0+tx_1 $$

$$ x= 1+t $$

$$ y = (1-t)y_0+t(y_1) $$

$$ y=1 $$

parametrizes the **straignt line** from one point to the other, so yes, you need to parametrize like you did in the second example. That is the simplest of all parametrizations that are available.

Comment: If I set y=t, and x=t^2+1, do the boundaries become 0 and 1? Because y=t and y goes from 0 to 1.

Comment: @says you are correct